# error Elements in iteration expect to have 'v-bind:key' directives vue/require-v-for-key

Tags: vue.js

I'm a total beginner of Vue. Since I am learning to create a commercial product page and I followed the tutor to code. After the tutorial had finished, the tutor could successfully open the demo page he has created.When I try to do npm run serve. I have received such error: **error  Elements in iteration expect to have 'v-bind:key' directives  vue/require-v-for-key.**

Here is the piece of code with  some problems that the VS code indicates:

```
  <div 
    v-for = "product in products"
    class = "product-item"
    v-bind: key = "product.id"
  >
```

I have no idea where to add the v-bind:key that VS code told to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove space between 'v-bind:' and the key attribute.
So final code should look like this:

```
<div 
v-for = "product in products"
class = "product-item"
v-bind:key = "product.id"
>
```